# Are closed type classes enough for inference of associated types (without type families)?

Tags: haskell, typeclass, associated-types

In the code below, ghc complains about ambiguity. I'm assuming it's because **type classes are open** (outside code could define new instance and actually make this ambiguous).

If I could somehow **close** the `Indexable` type class, would that be enough to make this idea a valid way to implement basic associated types?

**The question is more about theoretical aspects of type inference** than about how to get it to work in Haskell. Is the problem here a theoretical issue with such a system that would make inference not possible for `t1` below? Would allowing closed type classes be enough to infer `t1` unambiguously?

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

class Indexable a where

instance Indexable (String, Int, Char) where
instance Indexable ([(String, a)], String, a) where

test1 :: Indexable (a,b,c) => a -> b -> c
test1 x y = undefined

t1 = test1 "hi" 3 == 'c'

main = return ()

----------------------------------------------------------------
-- indexable.hs:14:6:                                         --
--     No instance for (Indexable ([Char], b0, Char))         --
--       arising from a use of ‘test1’                        --
--     The type variable ‘b0’ is ambiguous                    --
--     Note: there is a potential instance available:         --
--       instance Indexable (String, Int, Char)               --
--         -- Defined at indexable.hs:8:10                    --
--     In the first argument of ‘(==)’, namely ‘test1 "hi" 3’ --
--     In the expression: test1 "hi" 3 == 'c'                 --
--     In an equation for ‘t1’: t1 = test1 "hi" 3 == 'c'      --
--                                                            --
-- indexable.hs:14:17:                                        --
--     No instance for (Num b0) arising from the literal ‘3’  --
--     The type variable ‘b0’ is ambiguous                    --
--     Note: there are several potential instances:           --
--       instance Num Double -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’        --
--       instance Num Float -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’         --
--       instance Integral a => Num (GHC.Real.Ratio a)        --
--         -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’                           --
--       ...plus three others                                 --
--     In the second argument of ‘test1’, namely ‘3’          --
--     In the first argument of ‘(==)’, namely ‘test1 "hi" 3’ --
--     In the expression: test1 "hi" 3 == 'c'                 --
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I'm wondering that too. Why not use type families?

Comment: Motivation: provide a basic associated types feature when designing a type system, but do it in a simple (for the type checker) way. Not intended to be used in Haskell

Comment: @dfeuer updated the question to clarify and also see comment above

Comment: The **polymorphic** type of `t1` **is** inferable. Disable the monomorphism restriction, as directed in the first paragraph of my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28709551/414413). The type is not only theoretically inferable, but is practically inferable.

Comment: @Cirdec Thanks! That still isn't exactly what I'm after. I've updated the question to include the `NoMonomorphismRestriction` flag and changed the example to show that the problem still exists: the type of `3` in `t1 = test1 "hi" 3 == 'c'` still can't be inferred, it is considered ambiguous. The reason is openness of type classes, as I understand.

Comment: The type of `3` in your *new* `t1` can't be inferred (perhaps it should have a different name than `t1`; I'll call it `t2`?). Consider `t3 x = test1 "hi" x == 'c'`. It has the inferred type `t3 :: Indexable ([Char], b, Char) => b -> Bool` from which we can deduce that `x` has the inferred type `x :: Indexable ([Char], b, Char) => b`. The best inferred type of `3` would then be `Num b, Indexable ([Char], b, Char) => b`. `3` needs to have a concrete type because it's type isn't involved in the return type of `t2 :: Bool`.

Comment: @Cirdec right, but why is the type of x generalized in your example? Because we can't know which type is going to be used. However if the type class was allowed to be closed, we could say for certain that your `b` type must be Int to type check.

Comment: @sinelaw Knowing that the key has a `Num` instance and that `Indexable` is closed and the only possible keys are `Int` and `String` isn't enough to know that the key must be `Int`. You would also need to know that there will never be a `Num` instance for `String`, implying that `Num` is also closed. Alternatively, you could tell that you must be using the instance where the container is a `String` from the fact that the container isn't a `[(String, a)]` and knowing `Indexable` is closed. Choosing the instance based on the container is exactly what you'd do with fundeps or type families.

Comment: @Cirdec OK nice! Add this to your answer and I'll accept

Answer (score 4):

This error is caused by the dreaded [monomorphism restriction](https://wiki.haskell.org/Monomorphism_restriction). Disable it with `NoMonomorphismRestriction`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}
```

This problem is a good example of where you should use `MultiParamTypeClasses` and `newtype`s.

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}

import Data.Maybe

class Indexable k v c where
    at :: c -> k -> Maybe v
```

An ordinary list is `Indexable` by `Int`.

```
instance Indexable Int a [a] where
    c `at` k = listToMaybe  . drop k $ c
```

A list that has the special meaning of being an association list can easily be `Indexable` in a different way if it's wrapped in a `newtype`.

```
newtype Assoc k v = Assoc {getAssoc :: [(k, v)]}

instance (Eq k) => Indexable k v (Assoc k v) where
    c `at` k = fmap snd . listToMaybe  . filter ((== k) . fst) . getAssoc $ c
```

With `NoMonomorphismRestriction` or an explicit signature the test snipped will compile.

```
-- t1 :: Indexable Int v [Char] => Maybe v
t1 = "hi" `at` (3 :: Int)
```

The `Indexable` class can be improved further by using `FunctionalDependencies` or `TypeFamilies` to help the compiler infer the involved types.

```
{-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies #-}

class Indexable k v c | c -> k, c -> v where
    at :: c -> k -> Maybe v
```

Comment: Is there a way for the type to be inferred without fundeps or type families? Not necessarily in Haskell as it is, also more theoretically